# Ajax Call returns [object,object]

Tags: ajax, laravel

when i am trying to alert data, it returns correct information in alert, i am using this code for alert;

```
alert(JSON.stringify(data['qualifs']));
```

when i am trying to view same data in my text box, it returns [object,object].

```
var qual = data['qualifs'];

$('#qual').attr("value",qual);
```

**Complete:**

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "teachers/" + $(this).attr("value") + "/edit",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
alert( data['qualifs']);

alert(JSON.stringify(data['qualifs'])); //returns correct data
var qual = data['qualifs']; //returns object

$('#qual').attr("value",qual); //text box
  });
        });
    });
```

Comment: It is possible what you're getting is an array. I doubt if you can see the values by trying to alert them, you can try using console.log(data).

Comment: here is output in alert: [  {    "qual": "HSSC",    "arb_qual": "الثانوي"  },  {    "qual": "M.A",    "arb_qual": "ماجستير"  }]

Comment: yes i can see data in console.

Comment: Excellent, if that doesn't solve your challenge, may I know how else to help?

Comment: i want to show data in select box or text box.

Comment: Ok... please change your question and add a sample code where you want your objects

Comment: it is already there; $('#qual').attr("value",qual); //text box id

Comment: it is already there; $('#qual').attr("value",qual); //text box id

Comment: If you're trying to perform an edit, it is only supposed to return one record if your db is structured properly. In this case, it returns more than one object implying that you have to perform a loop.